# Изменение заголовка при перетаскивании формы

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.x, форма

Тут даже не знаю, где копать Если ты перетащил форму, должен смениться заголовок.

Comment: @statkr, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "формой"?

Comment: @Xyanight под формой принимается окно, в котором несколько баттонов и выполняемых функций.

Comment: Все разобрался(САм себе ответить немогу рейтинга мало)
Я через root.geometry сделал. Написал функцую которая при изменении значений подставляет другой титл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root.title("Title")
```